# How to take numbers from an sql table and add them and display it in html?

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm quite new to PHP and SQL. I'm trying to get values from my SQL table and add them together and then display it in HTML. It's a basic inventory system where after an entry is made, it shows how many entries are there in total. I don't really know if PHP or SQL is the right code to use. I've tried searching around for an answer but I can't really find anything on it. I tried something on my own, but I seriously doubt this is far from what I'm trying to achieve. If there is a website or another link that is answering the same question, please let me know. Here is my code.

```
    <div class="card-content">
      <p class="category">Sales</p>
      <h3 class="title">
        <?php
        db_connect();
        $sumsale = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(price) FROM sale");
        print ($sumsale);
        ?>
      </h3>
    </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated it!

An example of what I want is the following in HTML. Now the table is an SQL table within a database.:

```
 <table>
   <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Price Sold At</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Type A</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Type B</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Type C</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Type D</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Type E</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Result. The `<p>` tags are the same, whereas, the `<h3>` tags will have the code that adds the values together.:

```
<p>Revenue</p>
<h3>61.00</h3>
<p>Number of entires</p>
<h3>5</h3>
```

Code that prints SQL table to HTML:

```
function createTable(array $results = array())
{
if (empty($results)) {
    return '<table class="table" id="export"><tr><td>No inventory yet.</td></tr></table>';
}


$table = '<table class="table" id="export">';
$keys = array_keys(reset($results));
$table.='<thead class="text-success"><tr>';
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $table.='<th>'.$key.'</th>';
}
$table.='</tr></thead>';

$table.='<tbody>';
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $table.='<tr>';
    foreach ($result as $val) {
        $table.='<td>'.$val.'</td>';
    }
    $table.='</tr>';
}
$table.='</tbody></table>';
return $table;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="card-content table-responsive">
   <?php
    db_connect();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory ORDER BY 1 ASC LIMIT 1000");
    print createTable(array_result($result));
   ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Also the `mysql_....` api wont access a SQLServer database. [Please read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly ahahha okay. Yeah, I've read that it's mysqli_query. My apologies.

Comment: No!!!! If your database is SQLServer you need to use the API I linked you to in my previous comment

Comment: You will also have to install the SQLServer Native Client and the php_mssql extension as it does not normally come with PHP by default

Comment: @RiggsFolly hmm okay. So then what I can do here? I'm still confused on how to solve my initial problem

Comment: You have to read the documentation

Comment: Okay, awesome. Thanks! @RiggsFolly

Comment: @MeharBanga Show us a sample of your table and the expected result you want to get.

Comment: @user4035 I just made the edits on the post!

Comment: @MeharBanga Show the SQL table please.

Comment: @user4035 umm how do I show you that?

Comment: @MeharBanga Select data from the database and put it into the table here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164475/discussion-between-mehar-banga-and-user4035).